# Logistic Regression TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, logistic-regression

```
logistic_regression.fit([x_train, y_train])
```

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Comment: just remove the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It is expecting two positional arguments one for x and one for y.
`logistic_regression.fit(x_train, y_train)`